# Add UrlArgs to reuire-js main file

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browser-cache

Is it possibile to add the urlArgs to main file?

```
require.config({
    urlArgs : "v=1.1"
});

<script data-main="js/main" src="js/require.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, here you call `require` before the script is loaded. In your `js/main` module, you can for example :

```
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs : "v=1.1"
});
require(['dep'], function(dep){

});
```

Or better separate the config into a dedicated module (as in this sample [project](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage) )

**UPDATE:**

If you want the parameters to be appended to the load of `js/main` you shouldn't use the `data-main` attribute:

```
<script src="js/require.js"></script>
<script>
requirejs.config({
    urlArgs : "v=1.1"
});
require(['js/main']);
</script>
```

or build the require object before loading as described in the [doc](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config) (I don't know the exact syntax for the config).

Comment: I tried the "simple project", but doesn't work. I added the urlArgs to common file, but this file has no the urlArgs

Comment: Ah, you wanted to have the parameters appended to the js/main load.